# Powershell - Search an array for presence of value from a hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am loading the header row from an Excel spreadsheet to an array and need to compare it to a hash table that has multiple key entries per value. I need to be able to have different variations for each column I am searching for.
The array contains the header row
(person name, Customer_Account_Number, Electric Company, company name, Service_Address_1, Service_City, Service_State, Service_Zip, Phone Number)

I need to set my variables like this:

> $nameColumn = 1 $companyColumn = 4

```
$headers = @()
for ($col = 1; $col -le $worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; $col++) {
    $headers += $($worksheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Text)
}

$headerMappings = @{
     "name"               = "Name";
     "person name"        = "Name";
     "contact Name"       = "Name"
     "company name"       = "Company"
     "service_address_1"  = "Address"
     "address"            = "Address"
     "service_city"       = "City"
     "city"               = "City"
     "service_state"      = "State"
     "state"              = "State"
     "service_zip"        = "Zip"
     "zip"                = "Zip"
     "phone number"       = "Phone"
     "phone"              = "Phone"
}

# Get column indices for specific field names using headerMappings

$nameColumn    = $headers.IndexOf($headerMappings["Name"])
$companyColumn = $headers.IndexOf($headerMappings["Company"])
$addressColumn = $headers.IndexOf($headerMappings["Address"])
$cityColumn    = $headers.IndexOf($headerMappings["City"])
$stateColumn   = $headers.IndexOf($headerMappings["State"])
$zipColumn     = $headers.IndexOf($headerMappings["Zip"])
$phoneColumn   = $headers.IndexOf($headerMappings["Phone"])
```

Comment: you're comparing a hashtable with an array, as aside, its not clear what `$headers` contains and its not clear what is your desired end result

Comment: Thanks Santiago, I updated the post to try and make it more clear.

Comment: What if the excel header contains multiple matches, like a sheet with both a `contact Name` and `name` columns? Which one do you want to pick?

Comment: Good question. I guess I would want to stop the process with an error since we would need to look more closely at the input file. It should only contain one column of each type (name/address/city...etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$headers` is an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays), `$headerMappings` is a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables).

I suggest a *two-step* approach:

- Create an array of *mapped* header names, using `$headerMappings` for translation; e.g., translate `service_address_1` to `Address`.
- Then base your lookups with `.IndexOf()` on the array of mapped header names.

```bash
# Sample input array.
$headers =  'person name', 'service_state', 'phone', 'service_address_1'

$headerMappings = @{
     "name"               = "Name"
     "person name"        = "Name"
     "contact Name"       = "Name"
     "company name"       = "Company"
     "service_address_1"  = "Address"
     "address"            = "Address"
     "service_city"       = "City"
     "city"               = "City"
     "service_state"      = "State"
     "state"              = "State"
     "service_zip"        = "Zip"
     "zip"                = "Zip"
     "phone number"       = "Phone"
     "phone"              = "Phone"
}

# Translate the headers to their mapped names.
# Note: This assumes that all headers names are covered by the hashtable.
$mappedHeaders = @($headers | ForEach-Object { $headerMappings[$_] })

# Get column indices based on the array of *mapped* header names.
# Note: .IndexOf() is *case-sensitive*.
# ...
$addressColumn = $mappedHeaders.IndexOf('Address') # -> 3
```

Note that if a given header array contains *multiple* headers that map to the *same* name in the hashtable, the above will only report the index of the *first* such header.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$headerMappings["Name"]`

`"Name"` is hashtable entry *value*, not a *key*; it is used in several entries, namely those with key `"name"`, `"person_name"`, and `"contact_Name"`.

Therefore, the expression predictably evaluates to `$null`, and the `.IndexOf()` call predictably returns `-1` (to indicate that the input object isn't part of the array).

If you wanted to do this without a intermediate helper array (as shown above), you'd have to do the following, which is *inefficient*, however, as it involves searching the entire array for every index:

```bash
$headers.IndexOf(
  $headers.Where({ $headerMappings[$_] -eq 'Address' }, 'First')[0]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77461020/45375) builds on your own approach of storing the column (header) indices in *distinct variables*.

An **alternative** is to build *another* hashtable that maps the mapped headers to the column indices.

```bash
$headerIndexMappings = @{}
$i = 0
$headers | ForEach-Object {
  $headerIndexMappings[$headerMappings[$_]] = $i++
}
```

You can then access the resulting hashtable with the *mapped* header name to retrieve the index of the original header; e.g., `$headerIndexMappings['Address']` or - more simply - `$headerIndexMappings.Address` yields `3` for the sample `$headers` array in the other answer.

Aside from not needing to define a separate variable for each mapped header, this approach has the advantage of the lookups being case-*insensitive* (as PowerShell's hashtables generally are), so that `$headerIndexMappings.address` works as well, for instance.